# Has an antivirus ever failed to detect malware for "non-technical" reasons?

Tags: antimalware

I'm wondering if an antimalware vendor has ever whitelisted (or otherwise failed to detect) a piece of malware because the author/sponsor either paid them, threatened them, or legislated against them.

Comment: I'm not sure any AV vendor would admit to that.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - this example is pretty old, but Magic Lantern was a spyware program written by the FBI that some antivirus vendors initially decided to whitelist.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Lantern_%28software%29)

> The public disclosure of the existence of Magic Lantern sparked a
>   debate as to whether anti-virus companies could or should detect the
>   FBI's keystroke logger.
>
> Concerns include uncertainties about Magic Lantern's full potential
>   and whether hackers could subvert it for purposes outside the
>   jurisdiction of the law.[7][8]
>
> Bridis reported that Network Associates (maker of McAfee anti-virus
>   products), had contacted the FBI following the press reports about
>   Magic Lantern to ensure their anti-virus software would not detect the
>   program.[citation needed] Network Associates issued a denial, fueling
>   speculation as to which anti-virus products might or might not detect
>   government trojans.[9]
>
> CNET News has surveyed 13 security companies about their contacts with
>   and level of cooperation with law enforcement authorities.[10]
>
> Graham Cluley, a technology consultant from Sophos, said "We have no
>   way of knowing if it was written by the FBI, and even if we did, we
>   wouldn’t know whether it was being used by the FBI or if it had been
>   commandeered by a third party".[11] Another reaction from this came
>   from Marc Maiffret, chief technology officer and cofounder of eEye
>   Digital Security who states: "Our customers are paying us for a
>   service, to protect them from all forms of malicious code. It is not
>   up to us to do law enforcement's job for them so we do not, and will
>   not, make any exceptions for law enforcement malware or other
>   tools."[12]
>
> When asked if Magic Lantern would need a court order to deploy, FBI
>   spokesman Paul Bresson would not comment, stating: "Like all
>   technology projects or tools deployed by the FBI it would be used
>   pursuant to the appropriate legal process."[13][14] Proponents of
>   Magic Lantern argue the technology would allow law enforcement to
>   efficiently and quickly decrypt messages protected by encryption
>   schemes. Implementing Magic Lantern does not require physical access
>   to a suspect's computer, unlike Carnivore, a predecessor to Magic
>   Lantern, since physical access to a computer would require a court
>   order.[15]
>
> Following the media coverage of Magic Lantern, F-Secure (a Finnish
>   anti-virus company), announced their policy on detecting government
>   spying programs: "F-Secure Corporation would like to make known that
>   we will not leave such backdoors to our F-Secure Anti-Virus products,
>   regardless of the source of such tools. We have to draw a line with
>   every sample we get regarding whether to detect it or not. This
>   decision-making is influenced only by technical factors, and nothing
>   else, but within the applicable laws and regulations, in our case
>   meaning EU laws.
>
> We will also be adding detection of any program we see that might be
>   used for terrorist activity or to benefit organized crime. We would
>   like to state this for the record, as we have received queries
>   regarding whether we would have the guts to detect something obviously
>   made by a known violent mafia or terrorist organization. Yes we
>   would."[16]